# Read all lines from a text file to dictionary python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Here I have a function that, when I read, only returns the last line. What am I doing wrong?

```
def read():
    with open("text.txt","r") as text:
        return dict(line.strip().split() for line in text)
```

The text file is pretty simple, two columns

```
asd 209
asd 441
asd 811
asd 160
asd 158
```

I want to read all the times into a dictionary, the `asd` part as the keys and the numbers as the value.

Comment: What's the problem? Is there an error? Are you not getting all of the data you expected?

Comment: Do you want asd to point to a list of all correlated values? If not you should use a list and not a dictionary!

Comment: The problem was dictionaries need unique keys, therefore I cannot have same keys with different values, I need to create a unique key for each value.

Comment: @GivenPie I am aware of what the problem was. But if the keys really matter so little and you can change them at will, then you should not be using a dictionary at all, don't you think?

Comment: @ShashankGupta I needed dictionaries to provide key value pairs, what other simple solution can give me that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary keys must be unique. You have only **one** unique key in that file.

You are in essence assigning different values to the same key, and only the last value is visible as the previous values are overwritten:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['asd'] = 209
>>> d['asd'] = 441
>>> d
{'asd': 441}
```

To store the *largest* value, use:

```
def read():
    res = {}
    with open("text.txt","r") as text:
        for line in text:
            key, value = line.split()
            if int(value) > res.get(key, -1):
                res[key] = int(value)
    return res
```

Comment: Oh... really. that makes sense!! Then can this allow the dictionary to take the LARGEST key instead of the last one?

Comment: @GivenPie: loop over each line, and only assign to the key if the value is higher than the previous value stored.

Answer (score 0):

To append values into a list for each dictionary key you can use a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read():
    result = defaultdict(list)
    with open("text.txt","r") as text:
        for line in text:
            key, value = line.strip().split()
            result[key].append(value)
    return result
```